# MySQL: How to get at most two images from each class

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables:

(1) `class`
(2) `images`

I want to run a query that dynamically sets a variable for all classes that are attending tomorrow, and then display the top 2 missing images for members of that class in alphabetical order.

e.g. something like this:

```
SET @class = (
    SELECT
        id
    FROM
        class
    WHERE
        attending > CURDATE()
    AND attending < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 DAY
);

SELECT
    class_id,
    NAME
FROM
    images
WHERE
    class_id = @class
AND image_path IS NULL
ORDER BY
    NAME ASC
LIMIT 2;
```

Which I would hope to give me something like:

```
class_id          name
4                 Anna
4                 Bjorn
8                 Alex
8                 Ceri
13                Adam
13                Donna
```

Comment: what is the current output?

Comment: Please share the `create table code` of the related tables. And also your current output

Comment: Sorry, no current output as it doesn't work - it's more hypothetical!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically an `INNER JOIN` between these two tables (class and images) would do the job:

```
SELECT 
images.class_id,
images.NAME
FROM class 
INNER JOIN images ON class.id = images.class_id
WHERE class.attending > CURDATE() AND class.attending < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 DAY
AND images.image_path IS NULL
ORDER BY images.NAME
LIMIT 2;
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT 
t.class_id,
t.name
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        images.class_id,
        images.NAME,
        IF(@prevClassId = images.class_id, @classPosition := @classPosition + 1 , @classPosition := 0) rank,
        @prevClassId := images.class_id
    FROM (SELECT @prevClassId := NULL, @classPosition := 0) vars,class 
    INNER JOIN images ON class.id = images.class_id
    WHERE class.attending > CURDATE() AND class.attending < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 DAY
    AND images.image_path IS NULL
    ORDER BY images.class_id
) t
WHERE t.rank < 2;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c661f/1/0)

**Sample Data (Class Table):**

```
id  class_name  attending

1   one         4/29/2016
4   Four        4/29/2016
8   Eight       4/29/2016
13  Thirteen    4/29/2016
```

**Sample Data (images Table):**

```
id  class_id  name      image_path
1     1       IMG_ONE   IMAGE ONE PATH
2     4       Anna      (NULL)
3     4       Bjorn     (NULL)
4     4       C4        (NULL)
5     8       Alex      (NULL)
6     8       Ceri      (NULL)
```

**Output:**

```
class_id    NAME
4           Bjorn
4           Anna
8           Ceri
8           Alex
```

Comment: This just gives me 2 rows _overall_ - I need (max) 2 rows for _each_ class attending tomorrow. The `limit` is why I assumed some kind of loop is in order?

Comment: That means for each class you want at most two such rows?

Comment: And please share the `create table code` of those two tables.

Comment: "That means for each class you want at most two such rows?" - yes correct. And I didn't create the tables, so I don't have the create table code, sorry.